# Chain rule doubt

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I have a doubt of appling the chain rule.
I have this $L$ function:
$$
L = y\cdot log(\frac{e^{a x+b}}{e^{ax+b} + exp^{cx+d}})
$$
I can rewrite it as:
$$
L = y\cdot log(p)
$$
where
$$
p = \frac{e^{v_{0}}}{e^{v_{0}}+e^{v_{1}}}
$$
$$
v_{0} = ax+b
$$
$$
v_{1} = cx+d
$$

If I apply the chain rule I have this:

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial p} \cdot  \frac{\partial p}{\partial v_{0}} \cdot  \frac{\partial v_{0}}{\partial x}
$$

But I know that I am missing somewhere the value of $\frac{\partial v_{1}}{\partial x}$

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$p=p(v_0,v_1)\\
\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{\partial p}{\partial v_0}\frac{dv_0}{dx}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial v_1}\frac{dv_1}{dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your result is wrong because $p$ is a function of $x$ that contains the two functions $\nu_0$ and $\nu_1$ but not in the nested form $p(\nu_0(\nu_1))$. So we must write its derivative using also the quotient rule as:

$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=\frac{e^{\nu_0}\frac{\partial \nu_0}{\partial x}(e^{v_{0}}+e^{v_{1}})-e^{\nu_0}(e^{v_{0}}\frac{\partial \nu_0}{\partial x}+e^{v_{1}}\frac{\partial \nu_1}{\partial x})}{(e^{v_{0}}+e^{v_{1}})^2}
$$

and the correct final result is
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial p} \cdot \frac{e^{\nu_0}\frac{\partial \nu_0}{\partial x}(e^{v_{0}}+e^{v_{1}})-e^{\nu_0}(e^{v_{0}}\frac{\partial \nu_0}{\partial x}+e^{v_{1}}\frac{\partial \nu_1}{\partial x})}{(e^{v_{0}}+e^{v_{1}})^2}
$$